# How to construct a graph with arbitrarily large girth and large chromatic number?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

Erdos theorem says it is possible and it is not so easy. What is the general procedure to construct graphs like Grötzsch graph?

Comment: I do not see any research aspect to this question. Hence it belongs at math.stackexchande, not here.

Answer (score 2):

Two explicit constructions as certain Cayley graphs of $\operatorname{PGL}(\mathbb F_q)$ and $\operatorname{PSL}(\mathbb F_q)$ are detailed in chapters 3 and 4 of the book "Elementary Number Theory, Group Theory, And Ramanujan Graphs" by Giuliana Davidoff, Peter Sarnak and Alain Valette.